# Curve ed25519. Compress private key

Tags: алгоритм, шифрование

Можно ли ужать(разжать в оригинал) приватный ключ из 128байт в 64байта? Сейчас сжимаю с помощью base58.

Оригинал : aa2c614de26d387b90199507503b093b7b31a2846c2d27e031638d8c1bd55de96f6eaa5fe7aa931d625ea541e4a489ebbd5f3cc3f9dedc6c13b65ce103fdf223

Base58 :
4QLNcPBageYnzA34ppejV5ttrWvorfxzVdHUxrkj7HwdZKpyBVS4CafKyyak842u4wGTZgKaH45mUpwd1TbB6XyL

Стал короче, но хотелось бы ещё ужать.

**Обновление**

Вопрос в том, как 64 байта презентовать в самом коротком строковом виде? Если хекс, то 128 байт, если base58 то ещё меньше. Можно ли получить строку в 64 байта?

Comment: ключи сжимать нельзя. Вы всего лишь записали в другой форме.

Comment: Тащемта, hex2bin из 128 байт в вашем формате даст ровно 64 байта сырых данных.

Comment: Пробуйте base255, например

Comment: В 64 байта можно ужать, только сделав бинарную строку, которая для вывода на экран будет непригодна.

Comment: Нужно пользователю показывать, не годится.